# Выполнение действия для каждого пользователя из БД

Tags: php, циклы, mysql

Коротко и ясно - выполнение в цикле действия для каждого пользователя из MySQL. Подскажите.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

.

```
$link = mysqli_connect(/* параметры */);
$users = mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT * FROM USERS');
foreach ($users as $user) {
    действие($user);
}
```

Comment: Не канает, нужно отправлять почту, а в итоге ни лога, ничего не выводит

Comment: @Виталий RS, не, я умываю руки с такой постановкой задач/детализацией.

Comment: Попробуйте так: :)

    $link = mysqli_connect(/* параметры */);
    $users = mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT * FROM USERS');
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        myFunctionToSendMail($user);
    }